# Using AVX512 _mm512_loadu_pd() on a column-major matrix?

Tags: simd, intrinsics, avx512

Suppose I have a matrix C 31x8 like this:

```
[C0_0   C0_1   C0_2    ...  C0_7]

[C1_0   C1_1   C1_2    ...  C1_7]

.
.
.

[C30_0 C30_1 C30_3  ... C30_7]
```

To set up a row of C matrix into a register using AVX-512 instructions.

If C matrix is row-major I can use:

```
register __m512d R00, R01,...,R30;

R00 = _mm512_loadu_pd (&C[0])

R01 = _mm512_loadu_pd (&C[8])
.
.
.

R30 = _mm512_loadu_pd (&C[240])
```

But if C is matrix-column, I don't know how to do.

Please help me set up a row of C matrix into a register in case C matrix is **column - major**.

Comment: If you want to transpose the matrix in blocks, you might want [`_mm512_permutex2var_pd` (VPERMT2PD)](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermt2w:vpermt2d:vpermt2q:vpermt2ps:vpermt2pd) to shuffle 2 vectors together, and/or blending via merge-masking or a dedicated blend instruction.

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes, please tell me detail how to use this. I don't understand.

Comment: Do you actually want to load "a" row or every row? Or do you actually want to do some operation on each row? Can you modify your algorithm to work on columns instead of rows?